# How to use shape cut in particle edit mode?

Tags: particles, hair

I added a plane to the scene and want to cut hair in places where this panel touches them. But when I select this plane as shape object and click "cut", all the hair is just removed.
How do I use this tool correctly?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if you have to use a plane to cut the parent strands, but a method is to just choose "Cut" from the options available in Particle Edit mode (other options are Smooth, Add, Length etc.). then cut all your parent strands to the length you want.

Comment: @JustinLeppan, obviously, I can use the cut tool, but it is quite difficult to make all the slices perfectly even and at the same level. So I'm interested in how to use the panel as a "knife". This would make all the ends of the hair perfectly even and symmetrical on all sides.